# Key differences between rest API and connect rest API in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Need clear explanation for the different type of Salesforce API.

The explanation are a bit confusing which I have seen already.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest different is with file sharing

- REST API allows for providing `FirstPublishLocationId` which will share file with provided record
- Connect REST API requires 2nd call to share records using `/connect/files/fileId/file-shares` path